# Block site on firefox with selenium

Tags: selenium

I am testing a site with selenium where on each page there is an ajax call to another site that loads unnecessary information and making the page load slow. Is there a way to block that second site maybe using Firefox profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify your host file? e.g. :

0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com

or

127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, 127.0.0.1 did work on my local machine, but I want to generalize it because we have 20 grid machines and I do not want to be going through all of them and changing the hosts file, also developers might need to run the tests on there local environments.

Comment: No worries, we actually modify our host file in our tests and then revert them back, but that is an ugly solution.

Comment: I am unable to enable it without restarting the computer. After I add the line it doesn't go into effect until I restart, but removing that line doesn't need a restart for some reason.

Comment: Actually it works, just takes about a minute to start working for some reason. I will try adding to my code.

Comment: What would be a good way to change the hosts file on the grid machines? Is there a way to do it through java? It is always reading the local hosts file and not the one on the grid machine.

Comment: I think if you modify the hosts file before opening a browser you shouldn't have to restart. You can change the hosts file programmatically by reading the file, adding a line then writing the file in the BeforeClass and then you can revert in the AfterClass. It's messy, there is probably nicer solutions.